# Put some text inside image in email body

Tags: html, html-email

I've been trying for a couple of hours to build an email body which includes some text inside an image. I made tried this code but the text always displays below image. Any ideas?

Code:

```
<body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0;background-color: #486380;">
    <center style="width: 100%;background-color: #486380;">
        <table style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" style="margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="position: relative">
                                    <center>
                                        <img style="position: absolute" src="img/test.png" alt="Login" />
                                        <span style="position: absolute">Hello everyone</span>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you viewing the output in Outlook?  If so, Outlook doesn't support "position", or loads of other CSS... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

Comment: I am viewing my tries in gmail!

Comment: If you are going to use tables then why not use background image attribute on Table / TD

Comment: I’d try without any absolute positioning, and instead use a negative margin-top to pull up the span (must be made to display as block or at least inline-block as well.) The image dimensions are known upfront, I suppose, so figuring out what margin-top value is needed to achieve the desired result should possible.

Comment: It is impossible to make it happen.What am I missing?Please post an example if it is possible..

Comment: These elements are stacked, and not the way you would handle this at all.

Comment: @GeoDim there are many examples in your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i can suggest would be to make the image a background (on a `td`) and build your text content on top of it.

Use https://backgrounds.cm/ to generate the appropriate code and add your text between the `div` tags. Would also recommend using transparent png spacers to fill out any empty space with this method.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `position` is [not well supported in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), so that's not a great option to achieve live text over an image.

One option, as Gwesolo suggested, is to use a background image. You can generate code using [backgrounds.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/) and get pretty good coverage across email clients. Even desktop Outlook! But depending on the image's design or dimensions of the box it appears in, it could require some finesse.

A second option is to use a service like [Nifty Images](https://niftyimages.com/), which can generate dynamic images with custom text built in. It's not as accessible and might not display as well on mobile, but it's a dead simple, straight-forward approach.

Answer (score 0):

You want to "cover all your bases: as it were. I think the best approach is to use the td style, inline-css AND the [backgrounds.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/) tool.

```html
<body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0;background-color: #486380;">
    <center style="width: 100%;background-color: #486380;">
        <table style="width: 100%; max-width: 800px;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" width="600">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td background="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg; background-repeat: no-repeat") align="center">
                                <div style="margin:auto;">
                                       <p> <span style="font-size: 24px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff">Hello everyone</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```